# android CountDownTimer

Tags: android

Below is the problem i am facing at the moment.

i have an activity lets say A. On button(lets say B1) click in activity A i have started CountDownTimer and when user click's button(lets say B2) i have started new activity let's say B. My problem is that once timer onFinish is called i need to finish activity B.

i have searched many forums and internet but couldnt find solution.

Please help to solve this problem.

Regards

Comment: you can't seem to get your question across clear enough! try to be more clear! ha

Comment: Please post the code as to what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29: onNewIntent() requires that Activity B be singleTop. If it is you can just launch an Intent with a special flag that Activity B will receive and then destroy itself.
- You can register a broadcast receiver in Activity B and then send a broadcast in Activity A (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
- You can pass the timer limit to Activity B, start the timer in Activity B and not have to worry about it at all.
- My personal favorite: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html. Have Activity B create a public static Handler instance, and then have Activity A send it a Message once the timer expires. Moderately messy, but very quick.

Comment: Thanks a lot Femi for all these information. i am going for option four :-)

Comment: Hi Femi i am able to send message from onFinish() to activity B handleMessage(Message msg). But now how to finish activity B from handleMessage(Message msg)

Comment: You should just be able to invoke the finish() method. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29 for more details.

Comment: Hi Femi, i am able to finish activity B using static refrence to activity B and calling finish() method inside handleMessage(Message msg). Is this the correct way to finish activity B from handleMessage(Message msg)?